# Why can't SQL Server Agent be started?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

A PC runs SQL Server 2016 (130).
[image]

I tried to start SQL Server Agent many times to no avail:
[image]

However, the Application group of Event Viewer shows it is started:
[image]

I found later the following in the System group of Event Viewer:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: SQL Server Agent isn't [a supported feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016#SSMS) of the SQL Server Express edition.

Comment: Thank you. How can I start SQL Server Agent for the SQL Server 2016 running on the machine?

Comment: On the assumption that the Express installer broke your existing installation, probably you need to backup all the databases hosted by the `MSSQLSERVER` instance and repair its installation.

Comment: Looks like Agent isn't actually installed for the main instance. Why do you have two instances anyway?

Comment: @Charlieface Do you mean why I have both SQL Server 2016 and SQL Serve Express?  This is a sort of development machine and has a lot of legacy stuff. I tried to uninstall SQL Server Express a moment ago, but I could not find it Apps & Features or Programs and Features.

Comment: Use the setup.exe from the installation media, which should have an option to remove it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept? I ran the repair of SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server Agent(MSSQLSERVER) was added.